# Use React to build parts of the application features

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

Consider having a web application that is based on a complex platform, however, you can design HTML Forms using its designer, and insert standard HTML elements, one of which is HTML Component. You can use this component to add HTLM/JavaScript code as usual.

I followed a tutorial to create a react app without using create-react-app. I managed to develop a sample React app using NodeJs, Babel, and Webpack and managed to deploy the final bundled JavaScript `main.js` on the target application. All worked fine. Below are the main two files with the source code:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
const App = () => {
    let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = () => {
        counter++;
        setCounter(counter);
    }

    return <div>This was created from React and Hello World!
        <h1>This is a test Header</h1>
        <button onClick={increment}>Click here to increment</button>
        <br/>
        <span>{counter}</span>
    </div>
}

export default App;
```

The Form HTML Component in the Target Web Application:

```
<div id="root">This Text should be replaced by the React App</div>
<script src="./target/app/path/public/main.js"></script>
```

Mind you that I ran the command `npm run build` and it generated the final script `main.js` which is deployed to the target application.

I am planning to start using React to build specific components for example a combination of Drop-Down Fields and Grid elements which are populated using REST APIs.

The problem is that I have to have one entry JavaScript source file that will render the component using `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))`, and if I develop say 100 components, but not all of them will be rendered when any Application Form is loaded. I think if the React `render()` function is invoked and the target DOM element is not present, then it will throw an error (I am not sure though).

So the question is how to design the application so that I can follow the above approach and ensure that the intended React Component will kick in only when the related Form is loaded or active.

I am thinking to import all the Components in `index.js` and develop a method to detect if the Form is active and needs a component, then it will invoke the function `ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector("#MyComponentId"))`.

I am not sure how to implement that and I need help. I appreciate your feedback.

[image]
[image]